# .htaccess not allowing to access project directory in wamp server

Tags: php, .htaccess, wampserver

This is my htaccess file code. This code is not allowing me to access my project directory.

**Code**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1
```

Please help me in solving this problem. Thanks

**Error:**

The server encountered an internal error or misconfigured and was unable to complete request.

Comment: Paste The Message Here Which Appears When You Access The Directory !

Comment: The apache `error_log` file should contain a more specific cause of the error, post any messages you may see in there as well.

Comment: This rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1` What this suppose to do?

Answer (score 0):

go to `Apache wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\httpd.conf`

and search for line

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

and un comment it

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

the problem will be solved !

Comment: Enabling `mod_rewrite` don't solve the problem. If `.htaccess` is there and `mod_rewrite` is disable, it will just ignore the file.